# The function VertexContract does not work in specific case

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am using the function VertexContract and I am experiencing that it does not work in some specific cases. If I give the graph with EdgeWeights, EdgeLabels and VertexLabels, I cannot contract {2,5} but I can contract {5,2}.

[image]

If I however specify the graph without EdgeWeights and EdgeLabels, both {2,5} and {5,2} work.

[image]

Why/how does this happen? And can it be resolved?

Comment: It would help people test out your question if you provided the code you used to generate the graph in the first place. It looks like this is what you used: grf = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6}, 
  EdgeWeight -> {2, 5, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5, 5}, 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"] 

I can confirm your reported behavior. Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Please provide [a complete minimal example](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/12). Without this, people are simply unable to help. You might give [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM)'s  `IGVertexContract` a try. Note that the syntax is slightly different—please see the usage message and the documentation.